# How can I add text to an image with Perl?

Tags: perl, image, text

I have got an image file which has 3 colors as background. I have also got a text file . I need to write a Perl script which copies text file on to the specific background color of the image file.

When I execute my Perl script , the script should ask the path for image file and then the path for text file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like a job for ImageMagick, [this page](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/annotating/) has some examples that should help you get started.

Answer (score 1):

I use [GD](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/GD) for this sort of work. [Image::Magick](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Image::Magick) will also do the trick.